# Power BI custom column

Tags: powerbi

We have some issues in removing some unwanted data from a large dataset.
The data set looks similar to the table below:

```
Inv_Number  | Type      | Week  | Quarter  | Amount  | Order
1           | Invoice   | W1    | Q1       | 100     | A1233
2           | Invoice   | W2    | Q1       | 50      | A100
3           | Invoice   | W2    | Q1       | 150     | A567
4           | CR MEMO   | W3    | Q2       | -100    | A1233
5           | Invoice   | W2    | Q4       | 70      | A345
6           | Invoice   | W5    | Q3       | 100     | A1233
7           | CR MEMO   | W7    | Q2       | -25     | A100
```

The expected filtered result should look like:

```
Type      | Week  | Quarter  | Amount  | Order
Invoice   | W2    | Q1       | 25      | A100
Invoice   | W2    | Q1       | 150     | A567
Invoice   | W2    | Q4       | 70      | A345
Invoice   | W5    | Q3       | 100     | A1233
```

Basically, we have a unique identifier (`Order`) and we need to remove all CR MEMO and related Invoices (partial or not)

I have tried the following:

```
HasCredit = if(CALCULATE(SUM('inv'[Amount]),FILTER(ALL('inv'),inv[Order]=EARLIER(inv[Order]) && inv[Type]="CR MEMO"))+CALCULATE(SUM(inv[Amount]),FILTER(ALL('inv'),inv[Order]=EARLIER(inv[Order])&&inv[Type]="ORIGINAL"))=0,1,0)
```

Then add the new calculated field to the filter and select only 0 (zero) should provide the desired output

**Further explanations:**

The data set speaks about invoices and CR MEMO can be understand as credited invoices. If you have one invoice (ex: Inv_number = 1) with 100USD credited entirely, you will have a new invoice (ex: Inv_number = 4) with Type = CR MEMO. Now, I need to remove those lines that are only linked by the Order and present the final output as already described. Keep in mind that one CR MEMO (credited invoice) can have a partial amount from one original invoice

Comment: Select only zero of *what*?

Comment: Your end result seems not strainght forward, meaning not only removing rows of where Type is Non-Invoice but also doing aggregate value for AMOUNT columns based on ORDER value... Question is how do you choose WEEK & QUARTER?

Comment: @wanna-coffee: we should consider that one invoice is prior a cr memo, that is how we decide the  week and quarter